# Resume broken apk download

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I am trying to install Asphalt 8 game which is 1.35 GB in size. However my wife network is erratic due to which the downloading stops after sometime. Is there any way to resume the download from the same place as currently the Google play store starts afresh.

Answer (score 0):

Get the game directly from Gameloft (or if the free version is missing, get it from p2p).

On Linux/Mac, use wget to resume your download. On Windows, use a freeware from snapfiles to resume your downloads.

The problem then will be to transfer the game from your computer to the android device.